# R: Preallocate memory for strings

Tags: r, string, performance, memory-management

I am joining very long strings together iteratively.

```
s = ""
for (i in 1:10^4)
{
   ############################
   ## Construct 'LongString' ##
   ############################

   s = paste0(s,LongString)
}
```

This process is very slow because at every call of the `paste0` function, R reallocates memory. Is there a way to preallocate the memory of `s` and then just fill the object?

Comment: Fill a `character(10^4)` with all the pieces and then use one `paste()` call with the `collapse` argument...?

Comment: Oh great! That would be a simple solution I haven't thought of. I guess you can make an answer out of your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option:

```
s <- character(10^4)
for (i in 1:10^4){
   s[i] <- <build some string>
}
result <- paste(s,collapse = "")
```